# Sampling Rate of Sensors

Tags: android, user-interface, runtime, android-sensors

Iam devloping an application which changes sampling rates between UI,GAME..during run time.Can any one tell me how to change the rates in run-time(function) and do i need to re-register the sensors after the change.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you will need to unregister then re-register your listener with the different sensor delays.

Comment: and do i need to stop the sensorchange event from firing...if yes how to go about it??

Comment: no it should be fine just registering/un-registering, I do a simliar thing in one of my apps and havent had any issues.